# How to override/disable "escapeHandler" of "Dialog" via XML-template in UI5?

Tags: sapui5

I know to override in UI5 the default behavior of [`sap.m.Dialog`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.Dialog)'s `escapeHandler` via controller, e.g.:

```js
this._oDialog.setEscapeHandler((oEscapeHandler) => {
    oEscapeHandler.reject();
});
```

The question is it possible to provide an alternative `escapeHandler` behavior via XML-template without using of `setEscapeHandler`?

Ideally, it should be something like `escapeHandler = "none/customFunction"`, e.g.:

```xml
<Dialog
    id = "authDialog"
    title = "{i18n>DIALOG_TITLE}"
    type = "Message"
    escapeHandler = "%CUSTOM_ESCAPE_HANDLER%">
</Dialog>
```

Particularly, I want to disable a `Dialog` closing on <kbd>Esc</kbd> button press and to do it in an elegant, declarative manner via XML-template, e.g. `escapeHandler = "none"`.

Comment: Related enhancement request: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1411

Comment: Give a  to the issue so that maintainers are aware that the fix helps also other developers :)

Comment: Also in https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1908 which is more a general request to fix the remaining properties that await functions but are still `"any"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a [new commit](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/16fad20e89b7beaf7a4cbe88831f9bea0ea9eabe) (merged today) that enables assigning controller function to `escapeHandler`. With that, the below code is now possible:

```xml
<Dialog xmlns="sap.m"
  id="authDialog"
  title="{i18n>DIALOG_TITLE}"
  type="Message"
  escapeHandler=".handleEscape"
>
```

```js
handleEscape: function(pEscapePending) {
  // Depending on the use case, call pEscapePending.resolve() or pEscapePending.reject() to overwrite the default behavior.
},
```

The fix should be available with the 1.86 release.

Comment: Santa comes this years even earlier than usual!

Comment: I've tested it on 1.86, everything is working great!

Comment: @MikeB. I just renamed `onEsc` to `handleEscape`. **`on`**`Something` is private by default (not just by convention, but also API-wise). And `escapeHandler` is NOT an event but a property which awaits a function. We can't [pass parameters](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/b0fb4de7364f4bcbb053a99aa645affe) there.

Comment: Thanks, why `pEscapePending` starts with `p`? Is it promise? I would call `handleEscape` as `escapeHandler`: `escapeHandler = ".escapeHandler"`. I've checked, there is no clash of names.

Comment: @MikeB. The parameter itself is not a Promise but it's a wrapper around the internal promise that handles escape [(src)](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/e01327e1bd5357286dbc171be588f036317cfe24/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/Dialog.js#L779-L787). On the other hand, the doc also mentions *"This property expects a function with one parameter of **type Promise**. In the function, you should call either `resolve()` or `reject()` on the **Promise object**."* ... Let's just pretend that it's a promise :)

Comment: @MikeB. You can name the handler however you want. However, methods beginning with `on` are private by default in the context of UI5 (_"if the property name does not start with an underscore or with the prefix "on", the property name will be automatically added to the list of public methods"_ [(src)](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.Object%23methods/sap.ui.base.Object.extend)) and are usually reserved for event handlers. Since `escapeHandler` is not an event and because the handler can be also used by other classes, the handler shouldn't start with `on`.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by putting the property `escapeHandler = "customFunction"` and then having a function with no implementation in the controller. Basically in `customFunction` I had a comment explaining that this is used to override the default escape behaviour.

Comment: I've tried your approach by adding `escapeHandler = "customFunction"` to the `Dialog` tag within the `Dialog` XML-fragment, but it didn't work out. Could you, please, share some code snippet, probably I miss something minor, but yet important.

Comment: I checked the code since I wrote this a while back and I used setEscapeHandler before opening the dialog so it's basically the same as you did. Your solution seems a little bit better, I also had the empty method instead of using oEscapeHandler.reject(). Sorry for misleading you, I also had a rough time finding out the solution and it seems that using escapeHandler="customFunction" won't work.